# How to display a single WordPress hook from different parts of a page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

There is a WooCommerce hook in single product page template, which execute 7 functions that displays title, rating, price, buttons, descriptions, etc…:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

How can I use `woocommerce_template_single_title` to display product title at the top of my page?

Then I would like to use `woocommerce_template_single_title` to display this title in the sidebar woocommerce template and for example in the middle of the page.

I am customizing my WooCommerce theme and I need to change some WooCommerce hooks behaviors.

Is there a WordPress function that filters or limits a WooCommerce hooks behaviors?

Thank you

Comment: @ankur-bhadania sir is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Product title in single product page, you can first remove it with **remove_action** this way:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

Then you can added it again at the top of your page with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
```

Or

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
```

You have to test which one is better for you.

> So know you know how to remove hooked function with **remove_action()** and hook it again anywhere in WooCommerce templates with  **add_action()**.
>
> When you use remove_action for an hooked function, you will need to use same priority. 
>   In `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook  `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` function is hooked with a **priority of 30**, so when using `remove_action()` you will need to use same priority.
>
> **Priority:** Higher is the priority, lower is the number (for add_action()).

Comment: @LayoutPH I have updated a little my answer for you. You are welcome :)